# "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type" in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot and JPA. It is [here](https://github.com/lapots/java-cloud-sample/tree/java_8_edition)

I've got a domain that looks like this. Also it seems `Entity` annotation is deprecated so I am using `@DynamicUpdate` instead.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

My `@SpringBootApplication` class looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.repository")
@EntityScan("com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.domain")
public class JavaCloudSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JavaCloudSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    // executed after all beans instantiated
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner data(PersonRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            repository.save(new Person(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Nike"));
        };
    }
}
```

The `@Repository` class looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

The `@Service` that uses this class looks like this

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService implements IPersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public Person findPerson(String id) {
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person generatePerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        person.setName("Nike");
        return person;
    }
}
```

But when I start application I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.domain.Person
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.app.JavaCloudSampleApplication.main(JavaCloudSampleApplication.java:23) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.lapots.breed.platform.cl
oud.boot.domain.Person
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.domain.Person
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where did you find the statement that `@Entity` is deprecated? Because 'Not a managed type' basically means that `@Entity` is missing.

Comment: Well `entity` annotation of `hibernate` - not `javax.persistence` is deprecated

Comment: But `Hibernates` `@Entity` is just an extension to the `JPA` one. So if you add the `JPA` one to `Person` you should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019364/nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-clas)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Maybe `Person` needs the `Entity` annotation since you are using JPA.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, `Entity` was missing. I excluded `javax.persistence` for certain reasons so I had not `javax.persistence.Entity` available

Comment: also you need to add @Id annotation on your id field

Answer (score 22):

For those who are using **Spring Data 3** and are desperately searching, I realized after a lot of research and attempts that most older advices are valid for previous versions of Spring Data but not for version `3.0.0`. So all my attempts failed. I tried to:

- add some annotations (`@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan`) with or without the asterisk in the package name. I still got `Not a managed type: class […]` fatal error at the start of the program.
- add an `entityManagerFactory()` bean. I got a circular reference error.

In the end, I found [this official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa), which gives this [sample project](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/tree/main/complete) as example. This one uses **annotations from Jakarta** (ex: `jakarta.persistence.Entity`) instead of `javax.persistence`. And with Jakarta annotations my project started working.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Changed to `jakarta.persistence.Entity` also resolved my error.

Comment: Hi, I changed to ```jakarta.persistence.Entity```  still getting same error on native build.

Comment: This helped me after trying for hours. Thank you. Note that I also had to change the import of @Id to jakarta.persistence.Id .

Comment: WTF?? Why this isn't documented? This is a breaking change, I spent hours in this.

Comment: Where can I send some beer, errr... hight-quality pasture for you? Thank you. I replaced every javax for jakarta and it solved my problems.

Comment: Also note: all javax references are to be replaced by jakarta, including in build.gradle, jsp's (yep, we still have them) `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core"%>` and `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="jakarta.tags.fmt" %>`

Comment: This! I searched so much online and this worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

In Spring Boot, the base names of your repo packages must match the base names of your entity packages.

Example:
Given base name:

```
com.abc.mcm
```

Entity package name:

```
com.abc.mcm.entities
```

Repo package name:

```
com.abc.mcm.repositories
```

Comment: Answer would be better with a quick example

Comment: Actually worked for me. I was putting base package and not exact package the repository was under. I did this and I stopped getting this error.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `@Entity` in your model/POJO class as below,

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  //your model goes here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Writing up for people who will search in the future:

In your entity manager method from `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, set package which has DTO/POJO class to `setPackagesToScan`

Example:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.abc.mainRepository.model"});
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}
```

Worked for me!

(My POJO was inside the model package).

Comment: Hi kanika! I edited your answer and added some markdown formatting. You can have a look at the difference by clicking the "edited" link. It's a good idea to learn about it if you're going to be active on this site!

Comment: Thanks Lii, I appreciate the amendments made to make it more readable to viewers.

Comment: Good hint. I encountered same issue when both `@EntityScan` and 
`@EnableJpaRepositories` contained a list of packages and only one of them got updated during development. That way new repositories where visible but entities where not recognized as one.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is more than 3 years old, I would like to tell the solution which has worked for me.

Put all the classes/interfaces/repositories/models etc. in the same package. This will work.

Comment: You mean the same overall package or in the same base package? Meaning, repositories, entities, interfaces in the same exact package, say, com.sample.jpa?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error on my Spring Boot project.
I added a new package but I didn't edit `componentScan`.

It was like that and I got the error:

```
com.okan.entity
```

I just changed as I added:

```
com.okan.model.entity
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

`@Entity` add in to class then it will work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a multi-maven-module project, where one of them was the `model` package, and others were `microservices`. In my case, when I ran a microservice that used a class defined in `model package` (domain called in my project), I had to add the `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.domain"})` annotation to the `@SpringBootApplication class`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.domain"}) // add this so the spring boot context knows where to look after entities
public class DoctorServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DoctorServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your entity mapped in your **persistence.xml**? Because I was with the same error and then I realized that I haven't had the entity mapped there

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game, but for anyone stumbling across this thread due to a Spring Boot v2 -> v3 migration, the real answer is to replace any `javax` usages with `jakarta`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350585/upgrade-from-spring-boot-2-7-2-to-spring-boot-3-0-0-snapshot-java-package-java/75786362#75786362).