# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to deploy a `Spring-Boot application` with `Service` accessing a `JpaRepository` which is connecting to `PostgreSQL DB` at runtime using `JPA` and `Hibernate`, refering to connection properties in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

When I am deploying the built .WAR on Tomcat, the Application is failing to start with the error as given in below Error Log.

Can somebody please help out what is the meaning of this error?

**Note** I have noted the trouble points in `MyServiceImpl` and `MyRequestBody` classes but I am not getting the exact reason for the error, as I am new to Spring framework.

The definitions of the relevant classes in my Spring Boot Starter project are as follows:

> Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(<root package name under which all subpackages containing relevant classes >)
public class MySpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

> My Spring-Boot RestController class (autowiring the MyService class instance )

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
```

> My Service interface (I have not provided any @Service annotation)

```
public interface MyService {
    //all service method definitions
}
```

> Spring ServiceImpl class with the autowiring repository instance to operate on PostgreSQL DB

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

       @Autowired
       private MyRepository myRepository; <-- **ERROR -- Bean not found** 

       //other default services e.g. find, add, delete, update, etc.

}
```

> My Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRequestBody, Long> {
    @Query("select h from MyRequestBody h where h.column1 = ?1")
    List<MyRequestBody> findByColumn1(String col1);
}
```

> My Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable", schema = "my_db")
public class MyRequestBody { <-- **ERROR -- Not a managed class type**

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     private Long id;
     @Column(name = "column1")
     private String column1;

//getter and setter AND toString methods
```

> Error Log (on deploying .WAR on Tomcat)

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-28 15:50:23.282 ERROR 5320 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.rest.MyRequestBody
```

> After adding @EntityScan("entities_package_name")

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field myRepository in com.rest.MyServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.rest.MyRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.rest.MyRepository' in your configuration.

29-Dec-2017 08:22:25.023 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-boot-service]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rest.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rest.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rest.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        ... 45 more

29-Dec-2017 08:22:25.026 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/home/sunilg/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/spring-boot-service.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-boot-service]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which @Entity annotation are you used?

Comment: javax.persistence.Entity

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Spring is not aware of your entity. You need to denote `MySpringBootApplication` class with `@EntityScan("your.entities.package")`

Comment: Getting a new error after entering @EntityScan to MySpringBootApplication class. Edited my question with the new Error Log

Comment: Do I need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("package_for_repository")` to `MySpringBootApplication` class?

Comment: Yes after adding `@EnableJpaRepositories`, it worked!

Comment: EntityScan is a new annotation I learned and it worked for me. I am just wondering why Spring did not mention about it. I was understand the impression that even the entity classes will be scanned by scanBasePackage. Anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was missing `@Entity` & and `@Id` annotation in Entity class.

Comment: I have a similar error, however, I added an EnableJpaRepositories and an EntityScan annotation on the Application and specified the exact package. The entity has an Entity and Id annotation, despite all this it still does not care.

Answer (score 1):

You should put Entity class same module with Repository class,
If not , you should add @EntityScan to your application class

Answer (score 1):

We need to configure our entiy class packages with the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean by using setPackagesToScan() method.
Consider below example :

```java
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    bean.setPackagesToScan("your entity packaged name here");
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

example error "**UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appModelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jpaModelRepository'**"

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appModelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jpaModelRepository': Error creating bean with name 'jpaModelRepository' defined in com.spring.jpaRestApi.repository.JpaModelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRestApiApplication: Not a managed type: class com.spring.jpaRestApi.model.JpaModel
```

**environment: Java 17 project structure, spring 3.0.1**
This one uses annotations from Jakarta (ex: jakarta.persistence.Entity) instead of javax.persistence. And with Jakarta annotations my project started working.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841081/18631124

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem, but I'm not sure about your code but I'm writing this answer for others who visit with this error. I made a mistake by giving the wrong package name other than a combination of an artifact ID and group ID( small typo) and the issue was solved when I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
//if use builder you have to add package to scan 
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder
){
return builder
  .dataSource(dataSource())
  .packages("root path of package")
  .persistenceUnit("productenter code here")
  .build();

 }
</code>
```