# Why Spring boot doesn't recognize my second datasource config?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I'm not sure why Spring boot doesn't recognize my second data source which I think is configured right.

I'm keep getting this message: `...Error creating bean with name 'leadRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ref.api.test.lead.model.LeadEntity`

I setted the right path for`.packages("com.ref.api.test.lead.model")` but for some reason spring-boot don't check my entity there.

**PrimaryDsConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = { "com.ref.api.repository" }
)
public class PrimaryDsConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.ref.api.model")
                .persistenceUnit("foo")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

**AdditionDsConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.ref.api.test.lead.repository" }
)
public class AdditionDsConfig {

    @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "addition.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return
                builder
                        .dataSource(dataSource)
                        .packages("com.ref.api.test.lead.model")
                        .persistenceUnit("bar")
                        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    barEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://blabla..
    username: bla
    password: bla

addition:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://blabla2..
    username: bla2
    password: bla2
```

**LeadEntity**

```
package com.ref.api.test.lead.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lead")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SequenceGenerator(name = "lead_id_seq",
        sequenceName = "lead_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class LeadEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lead_id_seq")
    private Long lead_id;

    private String place_id;
    private String name;
    private String formatted_address;
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String postal_code;
    private String formatted_phone_number;
    private String international_phone_number;
    private String website;
    private String vicinity;
    private String rating;
    private String price_level;
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    private String types;
    private String place_url;
    private String utc_offset;
    private String opening_hours;
    private String email;
    private String logo;

}
```

**LeadRepository**

```
package com.ref.api.test.lead.repository;

import com.ref.api.test.lead.model.LeadEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface LeadRepository extends JpaRepository<LeadEntity, Long> {
}
```

**ApiApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EntityGraphJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableCaching
public class ApiApplication {
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019364/nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-clas?rq=1

Comment: You code looks OK, it should work! Or can you put the whole project on GitHub?

Comment: Give the code for the service layer where you are calling the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out why spring-boot didn't detect my second datasource.
Beacuse I had `@EnableJpaRepositories` on my `public class ApiApplication` so it was confused. 
When I moved `repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EntityGraphJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class` to my `PrimaryDsConfig` everything starting working. 
So just pay attention how many `@EnableJpaRepositories` do you have.