# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type - Multiple Databases in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to integrate 2 MySQL DBs in my Spring Boot JPA Application. I have followed the standard steps but still,
Steps Followed:

1. Added Multiple DB Credentials in Properties File
2. Created DB Configuration Classes to create Transaction & Entity Manager for Each DB

I am not able to resolve the below error:

```
[2020-03-24 18:07:48] - [Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'com.oxfordcaps.finance.filter.AuthFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e52a26b' of type [com.oxfordcaps.finance.filter.AuthFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e52a26b': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity.User]
[2020-03-24 18:07:48] - [Stopping service [Tomcat]]
[2020-03-24 18:07:48] - [The web application [finance] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]
[2020-03-24 18:07:48] - [The web application [finance] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
 java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:535)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:711)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:650)
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:130)
 com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.sendCommand(NativeSession.java:317)
 com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.configureClientCharacterSet(NativeSession.java:550)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1307)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:958)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:817)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]


    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity.User
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:201)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:151)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
        ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Application File

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.oxfordcaps.finance.repository","com.oxfordcaps.student.repository"})
public class FinanceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinanceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

}
```

First Database Configuration file
DB Configuration 1

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Database configuration
 * @author prashant
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"com.oxfordcaps.finance.repository"}
)
public class FinanceDataBaseConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                .packages("com.oxfordcaps.finance.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("oxfordcaps")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }



}
```

Second Database COnfiguration FIle
DB Configuration 2

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Database configuration
 * @author prashant
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "studentEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "studentTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.oxfordcaps.student.repository"}
)
public class StudentDataBaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "studentDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.second-datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "studentEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean studentEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return
                builder
                        .dataSource(dataSource())
                        .packages("com.oxfordcaps.student.model")
                        .persistenceUnit("oxfordcaps-student")
                        .build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "studentTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager studentTransactionManager(@Qualifier("studentEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }


}
```

This is the Propety file which holds the db information in YML format
Properties File - YML

## Database(MySQL) configuration

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://stagingAAA.YYYYYYY.com:3306/YYYY_YYYY?useSSL=false
    username: 0000
    password: 0000          
  second-datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://stagingBBB.XXXXXXX.com:3306/XXXX_XXXX?useSSL=false
    username: 0000
    password: 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely missing the **@Entity annotation** on your **User class** (or it is in the wrong package, not being scanned).

At least, that's what your error message says:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity.User
```

Answer (score 0):

In the stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity.User
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552)
```

It might be because spring is not aware of the entity User
Try adding the annotation in FinanceApplication.java

```
@EntityScan("com.oxfordcaps.finance")
```

This might also help [nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019364/nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-clas/48019457)

Answer (score 0):

> Not a managed type: class com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity.User

**First Database Configuration file DB Configuration 1**

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                .packages("com.oxfordcaps.finance.entities") // !!! have to be: com.oxfordcaps.finance.entity
                .persistenceUnit("oxfordcaps")
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake , @alex although it is not solving my error , now i am getting the same issue with the model class related to the StudentDataBaseConfiguration DB table