# Spring Boot with Kotlin and Jakarta Persistence: "Not a managed type" error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot project using Kotlin and Jakarta Persistence. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to run the application:

#### Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class Clue

**Project Setup**:

- Spring Boot version: 3.1.3

**Clue Entity**:

```kotlin
import com.jd.jtrivia.models.Category
import jakarta.persistence.*


@Entity
data class Clue(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val question: String,
    val answer: String,
    @ManyToOne
    val category: Category
)
```

**I've ensured that**:

- The `Clue` class is annotated with `@Entity` from `jakarta.persistence`.
- All related dependencies are from the Jakarta namespace.

**Project Structure**:

- jtrivia

  - src

    - main

      - kotlin

        - com.jd.trivia

          - JtriviaApplication.kt (@SpringBootApplication)
          - models

            - Clue.kt
            - Category.kt
          - repositories

            - CategoryRepository.kt
            - ClueRepository.kt
            - DatabaseSeeder.kt

Comment: what about project structure can you also share it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019364/nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-clas)

Comment: @AndreiLisa I have updated the post with project structure :)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I viewed the post you have attached and tried the '@EntityScan', unfortunately it did not have an effect on my program

Comment: @Holiday-Pineapple and did you try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.jd.trivia.repositories")` to JtriviaApplication class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

It appears the issue was related to an incorrect package import. When working with JPA entities, it's crucial to ensure that the annotations and their associated imports are consistent.

In my case, the correct import for the JPA annotations is from the `com.jd.jtrivia.models` package, **NOT** `com.jd.jtrivia.models.Category`. The fixed entity declaration is as follows:

```kotlin
package com.jd.jtrivia.models

import jakarta.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Clue(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val question: String,
    val answer: String,
    @ManyToOne
    val category: Category
)
```

Comment: happy to see that you in your own get it.