# Upgrade from Spring Boot 2.7.2 to Spring Boot 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: java: package javax.persistence does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

When I use Spring Boot 2.7.2 everything works ok. After upgrade to version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, I have

My `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-security-jwt</name>
    <description>spring_jwt</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-themes</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-annotation-processors</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-castor</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>liberation-fonts</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mpobjects.jasperreports.font/jasperreports-fonts-liberation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mpobjects.jasperreports.font</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts-liberation</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-customizers</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-custom-visualization</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-report</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-web</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-base</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-viewer</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-samples</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-webviewer</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-lib</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-webdesigner</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>reports</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--            <type>pom</type>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Entity

```java
package com.example.BLModel;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountId id;

    @MapsId("tenantId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
    private Tenant tenant;

    @Column(name = "account_number", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "account_name", nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name = "account_name_english", length = 128)
    private String accountNameEnglish;

    @Column(name = "account_name_chinese", length = 128)
    private String accountNameChinese;

    @Column(name = "account_name_korean", length = 128)
    private String accountNameKorean;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 512)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Short parentId;

    @Column(name = "internal_code_id", length = 128)
    private String internalCodeId;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private Short grade;

    @Column(name = "is_parent", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isParent = false;

    @Column(name = "account_category_kind", nullable = false)
    private Short accountCategoryKind;

    @Column(name = "is_postable_in_foreign_currency", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isPostableInForeignCurrency = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_account_object", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByAccountObject = false;

    @Column(name = "account_object_type")
    private Short accountObjectType;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_bank_account", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByBankAccount = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_job", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByJob = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_job_kind")
    private Short detailByJobKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_project_work", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByProjectWork = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_project_work_kind")
    private Short detailByProjectWorkKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_order", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByOrder = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_order_kind")
    private Short detailByOrderKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_contract", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByContract = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_contract_kind")
    private Short detailByContractKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_expense_item", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByExpenseItem = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_expense_item_kind")
    private Short detailByExpenseItemKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_department", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByDepartment = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_department_kind")
    private Short detailByDepartmentKind;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_list_item", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByListItem = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_list_item_kind")
    private Short detailByListItemKind;

    @Column(name = "active_status", nullable = false)
    private Boolean activeStatus = false;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private OffsetDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "created_by", length = 64)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "modified")
    private OffsetDateTime modified;

    @Column(name = "modified_by", length = 64)
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "sort_internal_code_id", length = 128)
    private String sortInternalCodeId;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_pu_contract", nullable = false)
    private Boolean detailByPuContract = false;

    @Column(name = "detail_by_pu_contract_kind")
    private Short detailByPuContractKind;

    public AccountId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(AccountId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Tenant getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }

    public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getAccountNameEnglish() {
        return accountNameEnglish;
    }

    public void setAccountNameEnglish(String accountNameEnglish) {
        this.accountNameEnglish = accountNameEnglish;
    }

    public String getAccountNameChinese() {
        return accountNameChinese;
    }

    public void setAccountNameChinese(String accountNameChinese) {
        this.accountNameChinese = accountNameChinese;
    }

    public String getAccountNameKorean() {
        return accountNameKorean;
    }

    public void setAccountNameKorean(String accountNameKorean) {
        this.accountNameKorean = accountNameKorean;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Short getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Short parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getInternalCodeId() {
        return internalCodeId;
    }

    public void setInternalCodeId(String internalCodeId) {
        this.internalCodeId = internalCodeId;
    }

    public Short getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Short grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public Boolean getIsParent() {
        return isParent;
    }

    public void setIsParent(Boolean isParent) {
        this.isParent = isParent;
    }

    public Short getAccountCategoryKind() {
        return accountCategoryKind;
    }

    public void setAccountCategoryKind(Short accountCategoryKind) {
        this.accountCategoryKind = accountCategoryKind;
    }

    public Boolean getIsPostableInForeignCurrency() {
        return isPostableInForeignCurrency;
    }

    public void setIsPostableInForeignCurrency(Boolean isPostableInForeignCurrency) {
        this.isPostableInForeignCurrency = isPostableInForeignCurrency;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByAccountObject() {
        return detailByAccountObject;
    }

    public void setDetailByAccountObject(Boolean detailByAccountObject) {
        this.detailByAccountObject = detailByAccountObject;
    }

    public Short getAccountObjectType() {
        return accountObjectType;
    }

    public void setAccountObjectType(Short accountObjectType) {
        this.accountObjectType = accountObjectType;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByBankAccount() {
        return detailByBankAccount;
    }

    public void setDetailByBankAccount(Boolean detailByBankAccount) {
        this.detailByBankAccount = detailByBankAccount;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByJob() {
        return detailByJob;
    }

    public void setDetailByJob(Boolean detailByJob) {
        this.detailByJob = detailByJob;
    }

    public Short getDetailByJobKind() {
        return detailByJobKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByJobKind(Short detailByJobKind) {
        this.detailByJobKind = detailByJobKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByProjectWork() {
        return detailByProjectWork;
    }

    public void setDetailByProjectWork(Boolean detailByProjectWork) {
        this.detailByProjectWork = detailByProjectWork;
    }

    public Short getDetailByProjectWorkKind() {
        return detailByProjectWorkKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByProjectWorkKind(Short detailByProjectWorkKind) {
        this.detailByProjectWorkKind = detailByProjectWorkKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByOrder() {
        return detailByOrder;
    }

    public void setDetailByOrder(Boolean detailByOrder) {
        this.detailByOrder = detailByOrder;
    }

    public Short getDetailByOrderKind() {
        return detailByOrderKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByOrderKind(Short detailByOrderKind) {
        this.detailByOrderKind = detailByOrderKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByContract() {
        return detailByContract;
    }

    public void setDetailByContract(Boolean detailByContract) {
        this.detailByContract = detailByContract;
    }

    public Short getDetailByContractKind() {
        return detailByContractKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByContractKind(Short detailByContractKind) {
        this.detailByContractKind = detailByContractKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByExpenseItem() {
        return detailByExpenseItem;
    }

    public void setDetailByExpenseItem(Boolean detailByExpenseItem) {
        this.detailByExpenseItem = detailByExpenseItem;
    }

    public Short getDetailByExpenseItemKind() {
        return detailByExpenseItemKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByExpenseItemKind(Short detailByExpenseItemKind) {
        this.detailByExpenseItemKind = detailByExpenseItemKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByDepartment() {
        return detailByDepartment;
    }

    public void setDetailByDepartment(Boolean detailByDepartment) {
        this.detailByDepartment = detailByDepartment;
    }

    public Short getDetailByDepartmentKind() {
        return detailByDepartmentKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByDepartmentKind(Short detailByDepartmentKind) {
        this.detailByDepartmentKind = detailByDepartmentKind;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByListItem() {
        return detailByListItem;
    }

    public void setDetailByListItem(Boolean detailByListItem) {
        this.detailByListItem = detailByListItem;
    }

    public Short getDetailByListItemKind() {
        return detailByListItemKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByListItemKind(Short detailByListItemKind) {
        this.detailByListItemKind = detailByListItemKind;
    }

    public Boolean getActiveStatus() {
        return activeStatus;
    }

    public void setActiveStatus(Boolean activeStatus) {
        this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(OffsetDateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(OffsetDateTime modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public String getSortInternalCodeId() {
        return sortInternalCodeId;
    }

    public void setSortInternalCodeId(String sortInternalCodeId) {
        this.sortInternalCodeId = sortInternalCodeId;
    }

    public Boolean getDetailByPuContract() {
        return detailByPuContract;
    }

    public void setDetailByPuContract(Boolean detailByPuContract) {
        this.detailByPuContract = detailByPuContract;
    }

    public Short getDetailByPuContractKind() {
        return detailByPuContractKind;
    }

    public void setDetailByPuContractKind(Short detailByPuContractKind) {
        this.detailByPuContractKind = detailByPuContractKind;
    }

}
```

error

```xml
java: package javax.persistence does not exist
```

[image]
How to fix?

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x is JakartaEE **not** JavaEE.

Answer (score 32):

There is no need to add hibernate-entitymanager artifact as dependency in pom.xml.

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa artifact is enough. You shoud just consider the following points.

**Replace Java EE 8 With Jakarta EE 9 APIs:**

Spring Boot 3.0 will be the first version of Spring Boot that makes use of Jakarta EE 9 APIs (jakarta.*) instead of EE 8 (javax.*). This entails that we will have to look for EE 8 imports with javax.* and replace them with jakarta.*. Typical EE 8 packages used in Spring Boot microservices include the following:

- javax.persistence.*
- javax.validation.*
- javax.servlet.*
- javax.annotation.*
- javax.transaction.*
- etc.

Be aware that packages such as javax.sql.* and javax.crypto.* come from Java 17 JDK, not from EE 8, so they are safe to stay.

**References:**

[Notes on Spring-Boot-3 Upgrade](https://betterprogramming.pub/notes-on-spring-boot-3-upgrade-a15e16f84862)

[Preparing for Spring-Boot-3-0](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

Comment: This is such a major blow. OMG. SB 3 contains a crucial update that shouldn't have been released in 3.x.x but because they did, I'm forced to migrate to 3? So stupid. OMFG. I'm getting so many errors just so I can fix this little bug

Answer (score 11):

I just went through this hell myself for at least 6 hours. The real answer is described in the [Spring Boot migration guide's section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jakarta-ee) where they point us to [base Spring's replacement of `javax` with `jakarta`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#data-access-and-transactions).

Basically all you have to do is a Ctrl+Shift+F replacement of (almost) anywhere you previously had `javax` and swap it with `jakarta`. If you're like me, for some reason my IDE didn't autocomplete or recognize it until I manually typed it in, so don't let your IDE fool you if it does the same thing. FWIW, this conclusion has been supported by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021815/why-has-javax-persistence-api-been-replaced-by-jakarta-persistence-api-in-spring/60024749#60024749) as well, but it's just super unclear from the author's docs that this simple of a change is all we needed to do.

I hope this helps you to not waste half your day like it did me xD

Comment: Ok, 6 hours, I lost 1 weeks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change "JPA API from Java EE" --> "JPA API from Jakarta EE", and add

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as dependency instead, you get the Jakarta EE dependency that's compatible with the Spring version.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the jakarta dependency. Since it has its full content in the ultimate version of Intellij Idea. In your case, this one:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And add these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by old version of `hibernate-jcache`. Fixed by updating to the newest one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```