# Basic Spring Boot application always giving 404/Whitelabel error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

My basic Spring Boot application is somehow returning only 404 on all endpoints and i'm unable to figure out why

Main file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.employee.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.employee.*" })
@EntityScan("com.employee.*")   
public class EmployeeApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@GetMapping("/healthcheck")
public String healthCheck() {
    return "success";
}

@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The server starts up fine without issues and no errors in the logs but whatever url I try to hit, whether http://localhost:8080/employees/healthcheck or http://localhost:8080/employees/all they all return 404. Not sure what i'm missing here

Comment: Add a SS of the project structure and attach some startup logs. Moreover, you can try to enable TRACE logs and see the logs when you fire the request.

Comment: Does SS mean snapshot?

Comment: yes I mean screenshot.

Comment: The fact that you already have a ton of annotations next to `@SpringBootApplication` indicates you are doing things wrong. Ditch all those annotations and keep only `@SpringBootApplication` and make sure that the `EmployeeApplication` is in the `com.employee` package not some other subpackage.

Comment: Did you specify `server.servlet.context-path`?

Comment: I thought the same too but if I do remove all of them i'm getting the following error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository': Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.interview.employee.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.interview.employee.entity.Employee

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841081/544982 This solution finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

try removing all annotations in the main file except @SpringBootApplication and if that doesn't work try using the constructor injection instead of @Autowired.